# jsf2 spring managed bean calling constructor and postconstruct only on tomcatstartup

Tags: spring, jsf-2, managed-bean

I am using JSF+Spring project my spring maanged bean is ViewScoped

my saving state is client.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Following is my bean i found that constructor of bean and postconstruct method got call only on tomcat startup when it is spring managed bean instead if it is JSF managed bean constructor and postconstruct got call on every page refresh.
Is it the real behavior if i want to call method on page refresh every time under spring managed bean what should id do ?

```
@Component
@ViewScoped
public class DataTableBean implements Serializable{

public DataTableBean() {
        super();
}

@PostConstruct
    private void loadDataData(){
        System.out.println("Post constructing");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering , what exactly is the reason you're still using Spring? Its DI and service benefits has almost disappeared since the new CDI API in Java EE 6 and the new EJB API in Java EE 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@Component` is a Spring specific annotation to manage beans by Spring. The `@ViewScoped` is a JSF specific annotation to specify the scope of a JSF managed bean `@ManagedBean`. JSF specific scope annotations does not work on a Spring managed bean at all. You should use the Spring specific `@Scope` annotation instead.

So, either just manage the bean by JSF:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
```

Or [homegrow](http://comdynamics.net/blog/109/spring3-jsf2-view-scope/) a Spring "view" scope (this is namely not one of the default scopes available in Spring):

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
```

Comment: Ok i Understand but when i use "@ViewScoped" with "@Component" what will be its behaviour ? currently it does not re-create itself at all and persist the data at client for till the tomcat get restarted, is it similar as session scope or some thing else ?

Comment: It will use the default Spring scope, which is "application".

Comment: After using custom implementation of view scope i am getting NotSerializable exceptions on my services implementations do i have to change them all ?

Comment: Spring services are indeed not serializable. I have no idea why not, Spring is beyond me. We just use EJBs which basically injects serializable proxies and we never have this kind of problems. Feel free to ask a new question to the Spring guys, maybe they can explain it or even propose a viable workaround/solution.

Comment: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor